# What is the meaning of fault_reg = ram [address] in verilog?

Tags: verilog

```
input [3:0] address; 
reg [3:0] ram [7:0];
reg [3:0] data, fault_reg;
fault_reg = ram[address];
data = fault_reg;
```

If the value of ram is 1010 and the value of address is 100, what is the value of data[0], data[1], data[2] and data[3]?

Does it mean data[0] mean bit No.0 = 0 of ram, data[1] mean bit No. 1 of ram = 1, data[2] mean bit No.2 = 0 and.....?

Comment: Well for one, ```address``` must be only 3 bits wide - because the ```ram``` 2D array is only eight 4bit words in size. So the value of ```ram``` cannot be 1010 - one or more of the elements in it can be.

Comment: well im writing a 4-bit data and maximum of 8 address ram

Comment: So if you are writing an 8x4bit RAM, how come you ask what happens if the address is ```10101010``` which is not a 3bit number in any base I know.

Comment: sry my bad the address should be 1000

Comment: Even ```1000``` that is not a 3bit number...

Comment: address should be 4bit? bit 0,1,2,3? input [3:0] address?

Comment: Not if there are 8 entries - it will be 3 bits wide. \$2^3 = 8\$. ```ram``` is declared such that the [3:0] bit is the **data**, the [7:0] bit is ```1 << address```. So ```address``` should be declared as ```input [2:0] address```.

Comment: the [2:0] address i get what u mean but the [7:0] not quite can you explain it more detail? sry for keep asking you haha cz im nt good in verilog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `address` is **four bits wide** and `ram` is declared as `reg [3:0] ram [7:0];`. This declares a memory as **nibble (4-bit) wide and such 8 nibbles**.

As shown in below figure.

[image: Memory]

In order to fully address all the 8 memory addresses, only **3 address bits** are sufficient. So, there is an **unused bit** in address variable. This will not give any **simulation issues**, but **synthesis tool** shall give **warning** about the unused bit of address.

Also, declaring `reg [3:0] data` gives 0 as **Least Significant bit (LSB)** and **3 as Most Significant bit (MSB)**. So, for your question:

> What is the meaning of fault_reg = ram [address] in verilog?

This **assigns/copies** value from memory `ram` at address of `address` to `fault_reg`.

> If the value of ram is 1010 and the value of address is 100, what is the value of data[0], data[1], data[2] and data[3]?

In this example, ram[4] = 4'b1010 so, ram[4][0]=0,ram[4][1]=1,... and so on.
Hence, data[0]=0, data[1]=1, data[2]=0, data[3]=1.

Refer to [Verilog Array Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643901/array-input-never-used/33644163) question for unused address bit and [Verilog Memory](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00024.htm), [Simple RAM Model](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/models/simple_ram_model/) links for further information.